# Starting a new activity via intent, sometimes works sometimes not

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclick, onclicklistener

Let say I have two activities and I want to jump from one to the other. I can do this in two way:

1) Directly, as a simple pass through
2) After pressing a button in the main activity

The difference in both situations is where I place my `intent` definition. In the first case, wherever within the onCreate method; in the second case, within an onClickListener callback. The code for both situations is as simply as this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

/*      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();*/

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
            finish();

        }

        });

      }

    }
```

For me, there is not sustantial difference in both cases. However, my app always crashes when I start the second activity from the button (examining the logcat, it seems that there is a nullpointer in the surface texture I use to draw a camera preview). If I start the second activity using the first method, everything works fine, telling me that the second activity is ok, the problem is in the way I am defining the intent.

What is the difference? Why when I call the second activity within the button my app crashes and this situation does not happen if I call it directly?

Hope I was able to explain myself,

Thank

Comment: You should post your logcat from the crash.

Comment: Pos your logcat, but I guess you have SurfaceTexture in your MainActivity, that is not initialized properly.

Comment: Post your log then we will able to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

When calling `finish()` on an activity, the method `onDestroy()` is executed this method can do things like:

1. Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
2. Close any cursors the activity was managing.
3. Close any open search dialog

   **update your with this:**

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
   btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  DrawingActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);          
       // no use of finish(); here
       }
     });
   }
   ```